# Problema ao chamar função javascript

Tags: javascript, funções

Estou fazendo uma aplicação web com javascript, meu arquivo js tem várias funções de CRUD, queria que quando o HTML fosse carregado, chamasse duas funções, então adicionei este código:

```
document.addEventListener('load', function() {
    ler() //le os dados do firebase
    mostrar() //mostra esse dados formatados
})
```

porém não funciona, qual é o problema?

**Edit:**

Como deram a dica, usei o `window` no lugar de `document` e coloquei um `alert()`, para teste e funcionou (o `alert()`), então suponho que outra coisa está causando o problema

Aqui estão o código de `ler()` e `mostrar()`:

```
function ler() {
    json = []

    firebaseRef.once("value")
        .then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var key = childSnapshot.key
            var obj = childSnapshot.val()

            obj.key = key
            json.push(obj)

        })
    })
}

function mostrar() {
    receitas.innerHTML = ""

    for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        receitas.innerHTML +=   '<div class="col s12 m4 l3">' +
                                    '<div class="card">' + 
                                        '<div class="card-image">' +
                                            '<img src="./image/default.png">' +
                                            '<span class="card-title">' + json[i].nome + '</span>' +
                                            '<span class="hide">' + json[i].key + '</span>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</div>'
    }
}
```

Ambos funcionam chamando as funções no console

Comment: Mostre na sua pergunta o conteudo da função `ler()` e `mostrar()` juntamente com o erro

Comment: Onde vc define `receitas`?

Comment: `var receitas = document.getElementById('receitas')` é uma div no HTML

Comment: Dá um `console.log(json)` pra ver se tá retornando algo, no final de `ler`

Comment: sim retorna os objetos corretamente

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema mudando a função `mudar()`, em vez de fazer um loop para mostrar os dados ela recebeu dois parâmetros (key e nome) e chamei a função passando os valores em vez de adicionar em um `json`

Comment: Este é um problema clássico para quem está iniciando com o Firebase: [Assincronia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/278696/39181).

Answer (score -1):

Por vezes, o evento `load` pode não ser disparado em `document`. Ao invés, use o `window`:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  alert('I am working!')
});
```

Comment: também não funciona

Comment: Tenta com o `alert`! Se receber o alerta, o problema está nas funções `ler` e `mostrar` @GuilhermeCostamilam

Comment: coloquei `ler()` e `mostrar()` na pergunta

Comment: Claro que falta fechar `)` **:)**

Comment: Valeu!!! @wmsouza

Comment: Cara, eu editei o código para envolver o `alert` em uma expressão de função porque acho que essa provavelmente era a sua intenção em primeiro lugar, uma vez que, anteriormente, o `alert` seria executado logo na avaliação dos argumentos a serem fornecidos à `addEventListener` (isto é, muito antes de _load_ sequer ser emitido).