# Leitura de dados do Firebase retorna sempre null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-database

Estou tentando ler dados de usuários que estão guardados no Firebase, através de uma aplicação Android. Estou tendo sempre `null` nas TextViews, mas vejo o valor no Logcat do Android Studio.

Já verifiquei as minhas regras de segurança e elas permitem a leitura de dados.

Esta é a minha classe que conecta com o Firebase:

```
public class FirebaseBD {
    private DatabaseReference ref;
    private Usuario usuario = null;
    private List<Usuario> listaUsuarios = null;

    public FirebaseBD(){
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    }

    public void novoUsuario(Usuario usuario){
        ref.child("usuarios").push().setValue(usuario);
    }

    public Usuario lerUsuarioPorId(String idUsuario){
        ref.child("usuarios").child(idUsuario)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        usuario = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);
                        Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                                usuario.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                });
        return usuario;
    }

    public List<Usuario> lerUsuarios(){
        ref.child("usuarios")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        listaUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();
                        for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                            listaUsuarios.add(snapshot.getValue(Usuario.class));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                });
        return listaUsuarios;
    }

}
```

E na minha MainActivity estou chamando ela assim:

```
Usuario usuario = new FirebaseBD().lerUsuarioPorId("usuarioTeste");
txtNome.setText(usuario.getNome());
txtEmail.setText(usuario.getEmail());
```

O método para criar um novo Usuário funciona. Só os métodos para ler dados é que retornam null. Tem algo diferente acontecendo no `ValueEventListener`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A razão do método de criar Usuário funcionar (e os de leitura não) é:

**O Firebase faz a leitura de dados de forma assíncrona.**

Isto significa que a leitura de dados é passada para uma outra Thread (chamarei de Thread secundária) que fica a espera do resultado e só devolve quando este estiver pronto (ou seja, quando o dado tiver sido lido).

#### Mas qual é a diferença entre assíncrono e síncrono?

Se a leitura de dados fosse feita de forma síncrona, ela estaria sendo executada na Thread Principal. Esta é a mesma Thread responsável por desenhar os elementos da sua aplicação na tela do usuário. É também a Thread que realiza várias outras operações da sua aplicação.

A leitura acontecendo na Thread Principal implica que essa Thread fique a espera que os dados sejam lidos para continuar a sua execução. Portanto, a sua aplicação não será mostrada na tela enquanto os dados não forem lidos. E se ocorrer um erro na leitura de dados, ou se os dados estiverem a levar muito tempo para serem lidos, a sua aplicação não irá executar mais nenhuma operação pois a Thread Principal foi bloqueada.

Podemos imaginar isso como colocar a comida para aquecer no micro-ondas. Nós só colocamos ela lá e deixamos a aquecer. Quando ela já está pronta, o micro-ondas nos avisa (através de um som) que já podemos ir lá buscá-la.

Ninguém fica parado enfrente do micro-ondas a espera da comida terminar de aquecer (como na leitura síncrona). Isso porque o micro-ondas não exige nenhuma interação humana para funcionar. Assim, você pode ir fazer outras coisas enquanto a comida está sendo aquecida. Bem eficiente, não é?

#### Corrigindo o problema no seu código

Agora que toda a explicação foi dada, vamos corrigir o código.

Eu **não recomendo** criar uma outra classe para leitura/escrita de dados do Firebase. Realize todas estas operações na sua MainActivity.

Então depois de colocar o seu código na MainActivity, você pode utilizar o resultado que você obteve da leitura de dados dentro do seu método `onDataChange()`:

```
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        ref.child("usuarios").child("usuarioTeste")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Usuario usuario = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);
                        txtNome.setText(usuario.getNome());
                        txtEmail.setText(usuario.getEmail());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                });
```