# Após recuperar os objetos com ValueEventListener o List não retém os dados

Tags: android, firebase, hashmap

Estou fazendo um Activity, que pesquisa no Firebase os objetos Usuário, percorrendo um HashMap com o ValueEventListener para exibir o resultado dentro de um RecyclerView.

O primeiro `Log` retorna o ArrayList `listaJogadores` preenchido corretamente.
O segundo `Log` retorna o ArrayList vazio, ou seja, logo após a execução do ValueEventListener os dados estão se perdendo. Já revisei todas as linhas, não sei o que pode estar anulando minha pesquisa. Alguém pode me ajudar?

`Grupo` é um Model

`este.getMembros()` retorna um HashMap

`getUser(id)` retorna um objeto Usuário

```
public void recuperarMembros(){

    // Recupera o time do banco de dados
    valueEventListenerTime = timeRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Grupo este = dataSnapshot.getValue(Grupo.class);
            membros = este.getMembros();
            for (String key : membros.keySet()){
                Boolean value = membros.get(key);
                listaJogadores.add(getUser(key));
            }

            Log.d("Resultado_primeiro", listaJogadores.toString());

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    Log.d("Resultado_segundo", listaJogadores.toString());

}
```

Como o Rosário esclareceu que a pesquisa no Firebase é assíncrona, eu alterei o meu código para atribuir o valor ao ArrayList fora do ValueEventListener para que os dados persistissem.

O método `getUser(id)` agora é o `listAddUser(id)` que ao invés de retornar um objeto Usuário, o atribui diretamente ao ArrayList, assim os dados persistem como eu esperava.

Muito obrigado pela ajuda. O código ficou assim:

```
public void recuperarTime() {

    // Recupera o time do banco de dados
    valueEventListenerTime = timeRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            time = dataSnapshot.getValue(Grupo.class);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}


public void recuperarMembros() {

    listaJogadores.clear();

    membros = time.getMembros();
    if (membros == null) {
        // Intent para MainActivity
        Util.irPara(TimeActivity.this, MainActivity.class, true); 
    } else {
        for (String key : membros.keySet()) {
            Boolean value = membros.get(key);
            if (value) {
                listaAddUser(key);
            }
        }
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}


/* Recupera usuário pelo ID */
public void listaAddUser(String id) {

    DatabaseReference database = ConfigFirebase.getDatabase();
    DatabaseReference usuarios = database.child("usuarios").child(id);
    usuarios.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            listaJogadores.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class));

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os dados não estão se perdendo. Eles simplesmente nunca estiveram lá. Isso porque [o Firebase faz a leitura de dados de forma assíncrona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/278696/39181).

Devido ao comportamento assíncrono, o segundo Log é chamado antes do ArrayList ser preenchido (por isso que aparece vazio).

Se você precisa fazer mais alguma operação usando o ArrayList, faça essa operação dentro do ValueEventListener (da mesma forma como você fez o primeiro log). Pois assim você tem a garantia de que os dados já foram lidos e inseridos no ArrayList.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Rosário - Baseado no seu esclarecimento, editei o meu getUser para, ao invés de retornar um Usuário, atribuí-lo diretamente ao ArrayList e funcionou como esperado.