# O onDataChange(), no addListenerForSingleValueEvent(), só é executado depois do meu método retornar

Tags: java, android, firebase

Estou tentando verificar se um dado email existe, com android usando firebase eu estou fazendo deste jeito :

```
public boolean existeEmail(String email) {

    final boolean[] retorno = new boolean[1];
    final DatabaseReference databaseArtists = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = databaseArtists.child(colecao).orderByChild("email").equalTo(email);

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                retorno[0] = true;
            else
                retorno[0] = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return retorno[0];
}
```

**Problema**

Está executando primeiro

```
return retorno[0];
```

E depois executa:

```
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists())
            retorno[0] = true;
        else
            retorno[0] = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

e está a retornar sempre false.Como faço para executar primeiro está função

```
 query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent()
```

Comment: [Problema clássico de assincronia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/278696/39181)

Comment: Eu preciso de colocar ela em uma classe.

Comment: Ao trabalhar com APIs assíncronas, como a do Firebase, o desenvolvedor é obrigado a pensar de maneira diferente da tradicional forma sequencial. Se fosse adicionado um pouco mais de contexto à pergunta (onde o método é utilizado, por exemplo) seria mais fácil de indicar alternativas para obter o resultado desejado.

Comment: Colocando códigos na Activity cria muita repetição de código.

Comment: Já viu a minha resposta? Necessita de mais alguma informação?

Comment: Já vi sim, desculpe pela demora, estava ausente.

Answer (score 4):

As consultas feitas ao FirebaseDatabase tem os seus resultados "entregues" de forma assíncrona.

Para receber o resultado é necessário indicar um *listener* que o irá receber, neste caso um [ValueEventListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener).
Isso é o que você fez ao usar o método [addListenerForSingleValueEvent()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query).

O código que se encontra dentro dos parêntesis apenas implementa a interface e cria um novo objecto.
Só quando o objecto [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query) tiver obtido o resultado é que o código dentro dos métodos `onDataChange()` ou `onCancelled()` é executado.

Como o tempo necessário para obter o resultado é maior do que o necessário para executar o método `existeEmail()`, é retornado `retorno[0]` com o valor com que foi inicializado.

Assim, o tratamento do resultado tem de ser feito dentro dos métodos da implementação da interface ValueEventListener.

Para isso tem várias soluções:

- escrever todo o código na implementação *inline* da interface

  ```
  query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          if (dataSnapshot.exists())

              //todo o código aqui
          else
              //todo o código aqui
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
          //todo o código aqui
      }
  });
  ```
- escrever métodos onde coloca esse código e chamá-los nos métodos do ValueEventListener

  ```
  query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

          handleEmail(dataSnapshot.exists()):

      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
          handleEmailError(databaseError);
      }
  });
  ```
- Implementar o ValueEventListener à parte

  ```
  public class EmailResultListener() extends ValueEventListener{
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          if (dataSnapshot.exists())

              //todo o código aqui, ou chamar método da classe
          else
              //todo o código aqui, ou chamar método da classe
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
          //todo o código aqui, ou chamar método da classe
      }
  }
  ```

  e usá-lo assim `query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new EmailResultListener());`

As duas últimas abordagens permitem a reutilização do código.

Resumindo:

Para receber o resultado é necessário disponibilizar ao objecto Query, através do método `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`, um objecto que implemente a interface ValueEventListener.
A Query usará esse objecto para "entregar" o resultado chamando o método `onDataChange()` ou, em caso de erro, `onCancelled()`.
A implementação pode ser criada *inline* (ex. 1 e 2) ou à parte(ex. 3).
O código que tratará o resultado tem de estar, ou ser chamado, dentro do `onDataChange()`.

Comment: Terei de criar uma interface que implementa o método ValueEventListener, Como eu vou poder ver o seu retorno?

Comment: Você tem de disponibilizar ao objecto Query, através do método `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`, um objecto que implemente a interface ValueEventListener. Ele usará esse objecto para "entregar" o resultado chamado o método `onDataChange()` ou `onCancelled()` em caso de erro. A implementação pode ser criada *inline* (ex. 1 e 2) ou à parte(ex. 3). O código que tratará o resultado(*"ver o seu retorno"*) tem de estar, ou ser chamado, dentro do `onDataChange()`.

Comment: Sim o resultado estará no **onDataChange()**, eu já implementei a lógica  do ex. 1, eu não consigo perceber como é que ele vai pegar o resultado fora do **onDataChange()**, sabendo que ele executa depois o **onDataChange()**.

Comment: Não dá para pegar fora. Aquilo que você faria, caso retornasse `true`, tem de ser feito no método `onDataChange()`. Substitua `retorno[0] = true;` por esse código. É porovável que tenha de ajustar outras partes do código. O método `onDataChange()` é como se fosse o método `onPostExecute()` de uma AsyncTask.

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece pois o processo de recuperar os dados do firebase é executado em background, ou melhor em segundo plano, por isso o retorno sempre será false. Você pode habilitar um dialog antes de iniciar o processamento em background, e desabilitando no final da execução.

```
dialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if ( dataSnapshot.exists() ){
            // Notifica usuário
            ...
            // Atualiza tela
            ...
        }

        dialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Poderia dizer se resolveu ou não seu problema? Nos dê um feedback.