# Problema com Leitura de Dados no Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-database

Olá,
Estou tentando ler dados no firebase e passar para um objeto,
mas quando eu usava esse objeto fora do **onDataChange** ele mostrava os dados do objeto como nulo

Então fiz os seguintes Log's para testar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public void readDatas(){

    valueEventListener = ref.child("users").child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            Log.i("test", "id 1 "+user.getCurrentCharacter());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    Log.i("test", "id 2 "+user.getCurrentCharacter());
}
```

E parece que isso acontecia porque tem um delay na hora de ler os dados do Firebase e passar para o objeto.

Como eu poderia resolver esse problema?

Agradeço desde já

Comment: Problema clássico de [assincronia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/278696/39181)

Comment: Coloque seu código sempre em texto, evite imagens para isso